# Nvidia RTX 3060 in Ubuntu 22.04 - Flickering/Brightness controls not working

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, brightness, 22.04

I have a Dell G15 with a Nvidia GeForce RTX 3060 Mobile graphic card. Just installed ubuntu 22.04 alongside with Windows, but I have two main problems:

- Screen flickers randomly.
- Brightness controls doesn't work, either keyboard and in the OS. Specifically when turning brightness up/down, there is no effect (brightness is stuck at max).

Here's my `nvidia-smi` output:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 515.48.07    Driver Version: 515.48.07    CUDA Version: 11.7     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   40C    P0    N/A /  N/A |      5MiB /  6144MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1507      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

My `ubuntu-drivers devices` output

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00002560sv00001028sd00000B5Ebc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GA106M [GeForce RTX 3060 Mobile / Max-Q]
driver   : nvidia-driver-470-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-510-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-515-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-510 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-470 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-515 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

And the output of `sudo lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`

```
pcilib: Error reading /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:08.3/label: Operation not permitted
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA106M [GeForce RTX 3060 Mobile / Max-Q] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Dell GA106M [GeForce RTX 3060 Mobile / Max-Q]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
--
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Rembrandt (rev c8)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0b5e
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
```

*Already tried changing the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line in `/etc/default/grub` to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi=linux"
```

also to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=legacy"
```

and then always

```
sudo update-grub
```

But no luck at all.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `nomodeset` is a wrong parameter.

Comment: @Pilot6 just edited it. Now it is set to `quiet splash acpi_backlight=legacy`, but no effect at all.

Comment: Do you run `sudo update-grub` after a setting?

Comment: @Pilot6, yep, did that.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 updated that.

Comment: Nvidia + AMD is a problem in many cases.

Comment: When you type `xrandr` it provides a number of refresh rates to choose from. I would try a different rate to see if that solves the flickering. Also right after a "flicker" type `dmesg` and `journalctl -xe` see if any errors are reported. Plus Xorg has an error log you can check as does nVidia probably but don't remember those commands off the top of my head.

Comment: I have a `[drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership`, after checking some other posts https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/ubuntu-21-10-failed-to-grab-modeset-ownership-with-495-44/193867/47 I couldn't find a working solution so far

Answer (score 0):

You have a hybrid GPU (prime) setup. The display is connected to the integrated AMD graphics and the Nvidia GPU serves as a 3D processor that you can offload 3D heavy tasks to. In other words, trying to control the brightness  through the Nvidia GPU is the wrong approach:
See if this helps find the right acpi_osi string:
https://iam.tj/prototype/enhancements/Windows-acpi_osi.html

EDIT: There may also be relevant controls in the BIOS that are overriding the OS.

```
Video
 LCD Brightness     
   Brightness on battery power - Sets the screen brightness when the computer is running on battery power.
   Brightness on AC power - Sets the screen brightness when the computer is running on AC power.
   EcoPower - Enables or disables EcoPower which increases the battery life by reducing the screen brightness when appropriate.
Default: ON.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The script added `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=legacy"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_backlight=legacy acpi_osi=! \"acpi_osi=Windows 2018\""` to `/etc/default/grub`, but unfortunately, it didn't help (brightness does not work either by keyword or OS, and the flickering persist.